# Where is the home directory on the sd card?

Tags: filesystem

My raspberry pi has stopped working so I want to get the files that I stored on it off it before I reinstall the OS. I have Raspbian from NOOBs and I am on a mac. On what partition and in what directory are the home and desktop located?

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS doesn't read ext filesystem by default. So you will need to use ext2fuse installed on your system. Here is a guide how to do it : http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/20/mount-ext-linux-file-system-mac/

Once installed everything, reboot and insert SD card. You should be able to see all the partitions available on your SD card.

If you don't want to do all this, I suggest you use a linux box to access the partition.

Hope it helps.

**Edit:**

Newer version of mac osxfuse (2.8.2) seems to be working fine with el capitan. I tested it successfully on my setup. Versions used : osxfuse (2.8.2) and fuse-ext2 (0.0.7).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can see three partitions on my desktop but there is one still unmountable. The three I can see are called boot, RECOVERY and SETTINGS. I have extracted root.tar.xz In recovery but found nothing. Where on what partition is my stuff stored?

Comment: @JonahFleming I've not really used noobs but I regularly access both partition of raspbian on my mac. And as far as file systems of noobs is concerned, there are multiple rootfs partition of all the oses that includes so technically you should be able to see no of oses + boot partition.

Comment: ok but home directory is stored where??

Comment: but where is home directory?

Comment: @JonahFleming It should be there in any of the partition, under /home/pi/... for raspbian, /home/user... for any other OSes

Comment: Any partition? It's not in boot or SETTINGS...

Comment: Other than boot or settings.

Comment: There is still one partition that cannot be read called disk1s6. In the recovery partition I have found two .tar.xz files called root and boot. I have extracted both but not found anything. Is it on the unreadable partition?

Comment: @JonahFleming I don't have any noobs card around with me to try it out. Lemme come back in the evening as I'm gonna try it my self.

Comment: @JonahFleming Have you recently upgraded mac os to El Capitan (10.11) ? If yes, ext support is broken currently using fuse-ext. Ideal solution would be running a virtual machine on mac, and using linux to access that partition. Hope it helps.

Comment: no I'm still on Yosemite